# Error "Parameter is not valid" when i minimized the form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

These are the Error Message that i'm getting when i pressed customize Minimized button.

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar.RecreateBackgroundBrush()
   at CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar.ParentOnResize(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnResize(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 clientWidth, Int32 clientHeight)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Are you using any image on this window?

Comment: @GaurangDave yea, have 1 image.

Comment: What does the debugger show you?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvmEt.png @Ben

Comment: It is a very generic error message, merely says "It did not work".  By far the most common reason is running out of memory.  The Bitmap class is a bit special, it is the one class in the framework where you can no longer ignore the need to call Dispose().   We can't see what RecreateBackgroundBrush() does, but very high odds is that it forgets to call Dispose() on the previous brush pattern.  You might have some more places in the code where you forget this, consider a memory profiler to find them.  If you're desperate then the fugly fix is a timer whose Tick event calls GC.Collect().

Comment: Fwiw, in the somewhat likely case you did not create this CircularProgressBar class yourself, you found a pretty good reason to delete it from your machine.

Answer (score 1):

When I started using new custom controls, I experienced the same error when attempting to minimize with a custom button. I could not figure it out until I looked at the detailed exception message.

> System.ArgumentException
> HResult=0x80070057
> Message=Parameter is not valid.
> Source=System.Drawing
> StackTrace:
> at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
> at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height)
> at Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuGradientPanel.Refresh()
> at Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuGradientPanel.OnResize(EventArgs eventargs)

It was the new BunifuGradientPanel, which worked fine before, it was minimizing all day, but I stepped away from VS for a few hours and when I returned it started to error. Strange.

I am not sure but I suspect that the bunifuGradientPanel1 is not disposing itself properly.

To fix it, just do this.

```
    public bool isMinimized = false;

    private void iconButtonMinimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bunifuGradientPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.None; // Un-dock
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            isMinimized = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           //...
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMinimized == true)
        {
            bunifuGradientPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;    // Re-dock
            bunifuGradientPanel1.Width = panelDesktop.Width; // maintain desired width
            isMinimized = false;
        }
    }
```

For people experiencing this same error but with non-Banifu controls, just do the same as above, but substitute Dock for Visibility. Your control is not rendering on minimize. So set visible = false when minimized. Set visible = true when you resize.

Right... this morning I realized that this error happens for my Banifu control when it is Docked. If undocked the error does not occur. But I need to Dock mine.

THE OFFICAL BANIFU SUPPORT RESPONSE: *Gradient Panel is being resized to a point where it cannot be rendered on minimize. We will provide a fix for this most in the next release. Most probably in the next release.*

**Cool, but I fixed it.**

Answer (score 0):

I just tried deleting the "panel" and creating it again and it worked.
The minimize button work again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).